# Как в слове заменить определенную комбинацию?

Tags: ассемблер

Есть задание:
Заменить в заданном слове комбинации 1011 на комбинации 1101.

Понятно, что будет цикл.

Как я могу обратится к младшим 4 разрядам 8-разрядного регистра (к примеру, Al)? 
Как мне затем выполнить замену значений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Для обращения к младшим разрядам нужно выполнить операцию and с маской 1111 в бинарном представлении.
2. Замену значений можно выполнить операцией xor с маской 0110 (т.к. мы знаем, что на этом месте у числа находится 1011).

Comment: Получается, нужно предварительно копировать значения, чтобы не попортить их логическими операциями?

Comment: Если нет возможности выполнить побитовую операцию, не попортив исходное значение, то — да. Точный ответ, конечно же, зависит от ассемблера.

Answer (score 1):

Если выровнено по 4 бита, то можно без циклов сделать 4 проверки, если по любому смещению, то сохраняем оригинал, устанавливаем маску в 110(bin), делаем цикл до 12(dec), проверяем при and $0f(hex) на равенство 1011(bin), при равенстве ксорим маску с оригиналом, потом сдвигаем с помощью shr, например, а маску с помощью shl и зацикливаем.